# Regarding the definition of vector field flow

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

> To make the connection to the Lie derivative, let $t \mapsto \Phi^X_t$
>   be the 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms (or flow) generated by the
>   vector field $ X $.   The differential $ d\Phi^X_t $ of each
>   diffeomorphism  maps the vector field Y to a new vector field  $ \mathrm{d}\Phi^X_{t}(Y)$. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields)

Not sure why $ d\Phi^X_t $ would map vector field $Y$ to a new vector field. Can anyone explain this? Also, what is the difference between $ \mathrm{d}\Phi^X_{t}$ and $ d\Phi^X_t $?

Comment: The Roman d is the same as the italic d.  Each $\Phi^X_t$ is a diffeomorphism of $X$, which is a map $X \to X$; thus, its derivative maps $T_pX \to T_{\Phi^X_t(p)}X$ for each $p \in X$.  Since this is a diffeomorphism, it's injective and surjective, and so starting with a smooth vector field on all of $X$ gives you a new vector field on all of $X$; you can check that this is smooth.  Also, your title has nothing to do with your question - would you mind changing it?

Comment: @PaulVanKoughnett But I believe $X$ is vector field here...

Comment: Besides, usually, $\Phi_t^V (x)$ means flow induced by vector field $V$ that maps manifold $X$ to $X$... But above seems different from that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought $X$ was the manifold in question.  If you replace all the $X$'s in my above comment by $M$'s, you should get a true statement.  The above $\Phi^X_t$ is precisely the flow you're talking about in your second comment.